Why is my Angular app not receiving Server-Sent Events (SSE) from a WebFlux backend?
I am building an application with a Spring WebFlux backend and an Angular frontend. My backend sends Server-Sent Events (SSE), but for some reason, the Angular app is not receiving these events, even though the same backend works perfectly when tested in Postman or with curl.
Here’s what I’ve implemented so far:
Backend (WebFlux):
The WebFlux controller sends SSE using MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE:
  @GetMapping(value = "/purchasedItems",produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public Flux<PurchasedItemData> findAllPurchasedItem(ServerHttpResponse response){

        response.getHeaders().add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-transform");
        response.getHeaders().add("Connection", "keep-alive");

        return purchaseService.getPurchasedItems()
                .doOnNext(item -> System.out.println("Sending item: " + item.getName()))
                .doOnError(error -> System.out.println("Error sending items: "+  error.getMessage()))
                .doFinally(signalType -> System.out.println("Streaming finished: " + signalType));
       
    }
    }
}


When I test this endpoint with curl or Postman, I see the events streaming correctly.
Frontend (Angular):
I’m using the native EventSource API to consume SSE:
private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/paypro/purchasedItems';
fetchPurchasedItems(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      const eventSource = new EventSource(this.apiUrl);

      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        try {
          debugger;
          const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
          console.log('Received SSE data:', data); // Debugging line
          observer.next(data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error parsing SSE data:', event.data, error);

          observer.error(error);
        }
      };

      eventSource.addEventListener('message', (evt) => {
        console.log('Received SSE data:', evt.data); // Debugging line
        observer.next(evt);
      });


      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        console.error('EventSource error:', error);
        debugger;
        observer.error(error);
        eventSource.close();
      };

      return () => eventSource.close();
    });
  }

In my Angular component:
  public loadData() {
    // this.purchasedItems$ = this.service.fetchPurchasedItems();
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.service.fetchPurchasedItems().subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log('Fetched data:', data);
        debugger;
        this.purchasedItems=[...this.purchasedItems,...data];
        this.cd.detectChanges(); // Trigger change detection
      },

      error: (err) => {
        console.error('Error fetching data', err);
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    });
    
  }


Proxy Configuration:
In development, I’m using a proxy configuration to redirect /api/events to http://localhost:8080/events:
proxy.conf.json:
{
  "/paypro/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}


Problem:
1.In the Angular app, the EventSource immediately triggers the onerror event with no data received.
2.The browser's Network tab shows the request to /api/events is made, but the connection closes immediately without any SSE data.
3.There are no errors in the backend logs.
What I’ve Tried:
1.Testing the /events endpoint with curl and Postman—works perfectly.

2.Ensuring the response header includes Content-Type: text/event-stream.
3.Double-checking the proxy configuration in Angular.
4.Adding CORS settings to the WebFlux backend:
java
@Bean
public CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    return new CorsWebFilter(source);
}


What could be causing the Angular app to fail when consuming SSE from the WebFlux backend, and how can I fix this issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

...using a proxy configuration to redirect /api/events to http://localhost:8080/events...
Unless it's a typo, those paths /api/events and /events are different.  What is the path used in the curl/postman tests?
The config probably needs a rewrite rule.
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""  # remove /api from the path
    }
  }
}


ey, thank you for the quick response!
I've updated the code since the previously posted version was slightly incorrect.
I appreciate you pointing that out!
